# What does it mean when a rabbit has clear mucus like poop?

Tags: health, rabbits, feces, defecation

On occasion we have had a rabbit with clear mucus like poop, some times it is rather well formed other times not so much.  In my experience it has mostly been with a rabbit who has a new or [preexisting digestive issues](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/692/what-is-wool-block-in-rabbits/720#720).  I was looking around online and found a few blog posts about similar symptoms in rabbits, but a good reference for a possible cause(s) and potential solution(s) is not showing up.

Looking for answers with scientific evidence, references and possibly case studies.

## Standing Bounty

Standing Offer to grant 100 [Reputation Points](https://pets.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) to a new answer that meets this criteria:

- The answer lists [reliable sources](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Identifying_reliable_sources) as supporting references.

> There is an existing [bounty system](https://pets.stackexchange.com/help/bounty) that allows that allows for the transfer of reputation from one user to another with the "Reward Existing Answer" feature, which I will use to transfer some of my reputation to you.

Comment: They are not supposed to be clear, but are you aware of the mucusy special cecotrope pellets, that rabbits produce? I am not sure I understand your description. So they are often well formed and solid-ish, but completely clear? I cannot see how an animal could produce clear fecal matter, mucus sure, but that is not well formed.

Comment: Yes I am aware of [cecotropes](http://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/1961) The dropping I am talking about here, are fully clear occasionally there are dark areas in them.  I don't have good photos and the bun who was making them has passed (at 13 years old)

Answer (score 1):

So, this may or may not be the issue and fix. Check your Bunny's mouth. If he has sores, an abscess, or a loose or cracked tooth, or inflammation in his mouth this could cause the jelly clear Pooh. What happens when there are sores is most bunnies reduce they're eating or stop eating thus causing GI problems, and the clear poo. Check his mouth. If any ailments are produced:

#1 course of action is vet visit, removal or abscess, or anti fungal or antibiotic depending on type of sores.

#2 Choice ONLY IF VET IS NOT AN OPTION- a spray I've used on my guinea pig for ring worm, my dog who had a tooth pulled, and my cockatiel I rescued who has wing damage. It's called Vetericyn Plus Wound and Skin Care. It's safe for all animals, can be sprayed in mouth, nose, eyes, and open wounds (safe enough to spray in a humans eye to cure pink eye). It has a gentle yet effective pain soother, and I always have a bottle waiting on hand. Check his mouth, and hope this helps. Vet is always #1 choice though.

Answer (score 0):

While this answer does not meet the criteria set forth to receive the bounty. It comes from a credible source and is worthy of consideration.

Presentation:

DIGESTIVE ISSUES YOU SHOULD ABSOLUTELY KNOW ABOUT – GI STASIS AND BLOAT Presented by: Melissa Ferry, DVM, MedVet Hilliard, [Midwest BunFest, Saturday September 17, 2016](http://www.midwestbunfest.org/)

During the part of the presentation focusing on bloat, one of the slides displayed an image of the mucus poop, I listened carefully and asked a followup question. This is what I learned.

In the experience of Dr Ferry, this symptom is associated specific to bloat. She and her practice partners believe it is created at or near the cecum during the episode of bloat, when it is passed it is considered a good sign, indicating the episode of bloat has been survived.