# Rabbit has mucous like poo

Tags: rabbits

my seven year old rabbit recently stopped eating as much as usual (he picks a little but not huge amounts). I thought it might be a cold of some sort because he has a runny nose. He has lost some weight. I began putting sugar in his water to help give him energy. He hunches in a ball when I remove him from his hutch, such as to bring in the house, but behaves normally in the hutch. This morning I noticed he had passed a mucous substance in his poo. There were balls of normal poo near it/attached to it. He is drinking as usual and I have seen him pass urine. My dad doesn't want me to take him to the vets as he is worried he will be put down, which I know I probably correct as I did some work experience there. He seems to have picked up over the past few days and seems at his healthiest however it's just the mucous stools that worry me. He is a fussy eater and will not touch any fruit or veg, he has hay but he uses that as bedding however I did notice him eating some. I was thinking he possibly went into gi stasis and the mucous built up due to a lack of cecotrophs. Because he has started eating a bit more now I thought it may be being pooed out because his intestines have some food in them again. Help would be greatly appreciated. He is missing his incisors however he could still eat and maintain a healthy weight before however unsure about molars as he hasn't been checked but I don't think it's dental as he was displaying symptoms of a cold.

Comment: i think you have to take it to a vet and do what is best for your pet and put your self aside,a vet dont want to put a pet down if he or she can help a pet in need(it is a lot more mony in keeping a pet alive and well)i have had to ask my vet to put down my sick pet several times in my life as the vet wanted to try to help but i know it was nothing anybody could do,so i put my pet before my own feelings even if it hurts me.

Comment: See related question [What does it mean when a rabbit has clear mucus like poop?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/10162/what-does-it-mean-when-a-rabbit-has-clear-mucus-like-poop)

Comment: I know but after using home care remedies he has picked up quite a bit

Comment: Not really much we can do online, he needs a vet check.  There is a lot going on.  You might [read this,](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/692/what-is-wool-block-in-rabbits/720#720) we had some similar issues and there might be something helpful in our experience.

Comment: Update : this morning found cecotroph like poo covered in mucous stuck to his rear end. This is a good sign?

Comment: I also just checked now and found more but with little mucous on it

Comment: He unfortunately passed away today